# I have made a Windows service that "works" but is stuck in at starting up

Tags: c#, windows-services

So a while ago I made a windows service that reads out a serial port and depending on the value that's returned it will change the system volume. The problem is when I run the service it's stuck in starting up mode but still does what its supposed to do. but it won't work if you have it set to Automatically start on startup. This is the first time I made a windows service so it could have a lot of problems.

here is the code that's running:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace audio_controller_WS
{
    public partial class AudioContorllerWS : ServiceBase
    {
        static bool _continue;
        static SerialPort _serialPort;
        public AudioContorllerWS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

           


        }
        public static void Read()
        {
            CoreAudioDevice defaultPlaybackDevice = new CoreAudioController().DefaultPlaybackDevice;
            while (_continue)
            {
                try
                {
                    String message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                    int convert = int.Parse(message);
                    defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume = convert;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }

            }
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
                      // string message;
            StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
            Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);

            // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();

            // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM10";
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            // Set the read/write timeouts
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            _serialPort.Open();
            _continue = true;
            readThread.Start();
            readThread.Join();
            _serialPort.Close();

        }
        protected override  void OnContinue()
        {

        }


        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I know my code should not be running in on startup but I doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: Does is show any message when starting the service?

Comment: Yeah it says 'error : 1053: the service hasn't answered the startup command correctly' something along those lines, but that's because all my code in in the on startup part. but that's kind of the problem if i were to put everything in on continue it doesn't have any errors but just not do anything it's supposed to. It runs in the background but when I send a signal it doesn't doe anything.

Comment: Where do you set _continue to false to exit the read loop? Also, you probably should not join the read thread in the OnStart. The service remains in the starting state until that method exits. The service will continue to run after the method exists so you can let the read thread run in the background.

Comment: Try wrapping the code in the onstart method in a new Task and let me know the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let the OnStart method exit. Try this:

```
public partial class AudioContorllerWS : ServiceBase
{
    static bool _continue;
    static SerialPort _serialPort;
    static Thread readThread;
    
    public AudioContorllerWS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }
    
    public static void Read()
    {
        CoreAudioDevice defaultPlaybackDevice = new CoreAudioController().DefaultPlaybackDevice;
        while (_continue)
        {
            try
            {
                String message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                int convert = int.Parse(message);
                defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume = convert;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
        }
    }
    
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // string message;
        StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        readThread = new Thread(Read);

        // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();

        // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
        _serialPort.PortName = "COM10";
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        // Set the read/write timeouts
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

        _serialPort.Open();
        _continue = true;
        readThread.Start();
        // don't join
    }

    protected override  void OnContinue()
    {
    }


    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _continue = false;
        readThread.Join(timeout);
        _serialPort.Close();
        // abort it if it hasn't exited
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked the only thing I had to change was moving the  _serialport.close() to OnStop as well.